# Where is a listing of the symbols used in iPhone app descriptions?

Tags: iphone, ascii

Is there a listing or simple copy/paste anywhere for the multitude of symbols commonly seen in app descriptions? Check marks, stars, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Edit menu of Xcode (and many other applications such as TextEdit and Safari) there is a menu item called "Special Characters". You can see a lot of different symbols in there.

[image]

Comment: +1, I tend to forget about this. BTW, the standard keyboard shortcut is `Option-Command-T`.

Comment: I should probably mention, that I assumed the OP wanted to use these symbols for his own app's description...

Answer (score 1):

That's not ASCII. That's Unicode. Try http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/.

Example: ★
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the actual colored stars and other symbols, you want http://pukupi.com/post/1964/ { found from a quick google }

I am not totally sure on how to enter those into an app description, but those characters may not show up as intended on a computer ( given they are all in the Unicode private use area ), but should on an iOS device.